# Passing a string variable through ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

The variable is passed through ajax and it is a database name. When the link is clicked it's supposed to retrieve a data from the the database. the link and the variable is on the same page. Here is the code for the link:

```
$x = strval($_GET['x']);    

echo '<a href="#" onclick="showInformation('.$x.')">'.$seatid.'</a>';
```

The $x variable contains the table name of the database. And here is the code for ajax:

```
function showInformation(str)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
document.getElementById("txtInfo").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","getinfo.php?x="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Here is the getinfo.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['login']="1";
$x = strval($_GET['x']);

$con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','Newpass123#','seatmapping');    
if (!$con){
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db('seatmapping');
$sql="SELECT name, seatid FROM $x WHERE seatid = 1";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die("Query Error " . mysql_error());
...
...
?>
```

I can't get it to work when i click the link it does not display the data from the table.
Please help me. Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks in advance..

Comment: exposing the table name is not a good practice..

Comment: `// code for IE6, IE5` ...I am speechless.

Comment: Not using jQuery ajax in 2014... I'm speechless. :)

Comment: @Nouphal.M is there other way to automatically populate drop down list of modules or php pages instead of table names? Thnx in advance.

Comment: Many things, 1. don't use mysql_query() as it is deprecated in newer versions oh PHP. see: http://us2.php.net/mysql_query 2. I dont see a reason for a session in this example because you are just giving them an automatic login without authentication, nor are you using it to save non-sensitive data between requests 3. Read about SQL injection 4. I second Nouphal.M in that you shouldn't expose the table name even if it is public information. 5. The issue you are looking for good be related to your JS, HTML, PHP, or SQL this is ambiguous as is... Try the PHP/SQL without AJAX first to check that

Comment: Build the JS and AJAX up from there, and REALLY take a look at SQL injection!! HUGE

Comment: @BRadC Thank you. You're the first person that actually gave help instead of criticizing. I'm planning to replace mysql_query once i get this to work. Im following old tutorials. I need the session for the getinfo.php to know which user is logged-in.

Comment: Is your function working? Check in console of chrome or firebug in Firefox.

Comment: You're welcome, forums can be harsh, but my guess is that you would want to use code more like: if(!$_SESSION['login'] == 1){die();} this turn away someone who has not previously logged in by terminating the script with die(), but without knowing the full context of your login system I cannot give you a 100% answer

Comment: get to know var_dump(); This will output a variable to the browser so you can see what is there... do var_dump($con); to see if your connection is correct, Also trying phpinfo(); to see if your PHP version is greater than 5.5.0 if it is then you're code will not work because that function is no longer included in PHP (deprecated)... Also find your server's PHP error log, that can help immensely... var_dump() and error logs are the beginning of debugging, and use firebug in firefox to debug JS as Rajesh Lohar said

Comment: Oh i forgot to include the !$_SESSION in that particular page. thnx for reminding. i'll tanke into consideration all youve said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try this:

Replace the line

```
 echo '<a href="#" onclick="showInformation('.$x.')">'.$seatid.'</a>';
```

With the below:

```
echo '<a href="#" onclick="showInformation(\''.$x.'\')">'.$seatid.'</a>';
```

This will solve your problem.

Comment: that makes sense without the \' \' you were sending an empty object instead of the string through AJAX, but still take a look at the security concerns I mentioned, you'll find that your session isn't keeping anyone out

Comment: @BRadC yeah that totally makes sense. i've looked in the error log as youve said, it says it is undefined. now i know. thanks for your tips. and thank you reminding me about the sessions..

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the `ID` of the expected element.

```
echo '<a href="#" id="txtInfo" onclick="showInformation('.$x.')">'.$seatid.'</a>';
```

Replace this line, instead

```
echo '<a href="#" onclick="showInformation('.$x.')">'.$seatid.'</a>';
```

Comment: that would be if you were trying to replace the contents of the a tag with the AJAX/SQL data, but you should make sure the HTML, possibly a div, with the proper ID exists

Comment: @Sagar Panchal i have a div that has id="txtInfo". Should i still put it in the <a> tag?

Comment: @rez, nop then find the proper file communication else use jquery ajax, it's quit easy my frnd.